# why does importing swing gives me an error in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

`import javax.swing.*` is showing unresolved reference to import i have tried to do some google searches and youtube but no result also tried to search for some dependencies
build.gradle:-

`plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'androidsupportmultidexversion.txt'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.intellij:forms_rt:7.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

}`

Comment: Why are you trying to use Swing on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **NOT** use `Swing` in Android

This is because `Swing` is developed for Java SE, while Android is based on Android's own implementation of Java. Since both Java implementations differ, you cannot use `Swing` in Android.

**Instead**, use the UI components provided by Android to build your app's UI. [You can follow this guide to build a simple UI](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui#:%7E:text=The%20user%20interface%20(UI)%20for,as%20buttons%20and%20text%20boxes.).

**PS**: If you are curious of how both Java differ, [you can read this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API).